# Ansible Networks error "operation requires privilege escalation"

Tags: networking, automation, ansible, privileges, cisco

I'm following along with a basic Ansible Network Engineer demo on youtube and am getting the following error:

---

ubuntu@DESKTOP-P91I0V3:~/Ansible/Networking$ ansible-playbook ansible-router\ play2.yml -v
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file

PLAY [Danny's Generic Router Configuration] ***********************************************************************************************

TASK [Global config settings] *************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [R1]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"}, "changed": false, "msg": "operation requires privilege escalation"}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************
R1                         : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

---

My playbook looks like this:

---

```
- name: Danny's Generic Router Configuration
  hosts: R1
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local

  vars:
    cli:
      username: admin
      password: cisco
      timeout: 100

  tasks:
    - name: Global config settings
      ios_config:

    provider: "{{ cli }}"
    lines:
      - ipv6 unicast-routing
      - errdisable recovery interval 60
      - security passwords min-length 5
      - ip name-server 99.99.99.99
      - no ip http server
      - ip http secure-server
      - snmp-server community ipvzero1 RO
      - snmp-server community ipvzero2 RW
      - ntp server 99.99.99.99
      - banner motd &**********THIS IS Danny'S ROUTER - DO NOT MAKE CHANGES UNLESS AUTHORISED! YOU WILL BE PROSECUTED! **********&

  register: print_output

-  debug: var=print_output
```

---

And my config file looks like this:

---

```
[defaults]
inventory = ./hosts
#host_key_checking = false
timeout = 60
```

---

I've tired with and without the "host_key_checking"
I have seen others in Stack Overflow with a similar issue but nothing that definitively resolves my issue.

I can SSH from my WSL2 Ubuntu environment to R1.

Can anyone help me resolve this "operation requires privilege escalation" issue please?

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
Lots of people suggested the "become" method which didn't work in my case.
The fix for me was just 2 lines which can be found in the Ansible documentation :
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/cisco/ios/ios_config_module.html

---

```
  vars:
    cli:
      username: admin
      password: cisco
      timeout: 100
      auth_pass: cisco

  tasks:
    - name: Global config settings
      ios_config:
        provider: "{{ cli }}"
        authorize: yes
        lines:
```

---

The 2 lines that worked are:

auth_pass: cisco

authorize: yes

I hope this helps someone else in the future.